# strrpos exhausts the allowed memory size

Tags: php

I have written a php function that should split a string up, remove  the whitespaces and put all single words in an array. I always get an error that the allowed memory size is exhausted and the document.write() command only outputs the last word. It says that the strrpos() command is exhausting the memory. How can I fix this code to work properly?

```
divide_search();
function divide_search() {
  global $search_string_php, $remaining_str;
  $pos_p = strrpos((string) $search_string_php, " ");
  if($pos_p == false) {
    $str_parts[] = $remaining_str;
    sort_search();
  } else {
    $p_part = substr($remaining_str, ($pos_p + 1), 
              strlen($remaining_str));
    echo $p_part;
    if(strlen($p_part) != 0) {
      $str_parts[] = $p_part;
    }
    $remaining_str = substr($remaining_str, 0, $pos_p);
    divide_search();
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe, `explode(' ', $search_string_php)` to get array of words?

Comment: `strrpos()` isn't using all your memory, it just happens to be the thing trying to allocate a few extra bytes after the rest of it has been taken up by `$str_parts`, or whatever is going on in `sort_search()` or literally anywhere else in your code because you're using globals instead of passing parameters around.